# "No credential specified" error in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've always used Jenkins CI for running tests, but now I want to use a pipeline for CD. I used this tutorial about Jenkins pipelines --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pts8zdHel5E

The status right now --> A build fails because there are "no credentials specified", while I'm using global credentials with username and password.

See here

[image: Pipeline script]

But every time I try to build, I get this error

[image: Jenkins Error]

And the authentication failed
[image: Jenkins Authentication failure]

Other work items in Jenkins are not failing, while using the same credential. Only pipeline projects appear to be broken.

What I've tried:
- I updated all the credential binding plugins
- Delete and create the credential again

Nothing seems to work in this project even in normal Pipeline script instead of Pipeline script from SCM

Comment: Do you have `.git` at the end of **Repository URL**?
It must be `https://github.com/twanbeeren/TourneyAPI.git`.

Comment: I haven't, but after trying it doesn't make a difference

Comment: The error: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/twanbeeren/TourneyAPI/' stays the same

Comment: I'm going to try and make my repository public, maybe that works

Comment: Making it public worked, so that's my solution for now

Answer (score 0):

When you add your personnal access token, jenkins creates
an internal Credentials ID realted to  that access. You need to provide that ID to the github agent

To get the Credentials Id, go to Dashboard > Manage Jenkins > Credentials
You should see an ID column with the ID string.

Copy that ID and then go to (Blue Ocean), edit the pipeline and select the github step and the github agent on the right side.

Paste the ID you obtained from the Credentials page.